# how to create horizontal scroll menu like google?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

How can we make a horizontal menu like the google picture menu?

Does anyone have the same code?

[image: like this menu]

Comment: So what is your question ? where you're facing problem ?

Comment: Post some code that you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is close to that i want
but its cant scrolling by mouse when i hide the blue scrollbar, just worked on mobile and other touch screen.
how i can drag scrolling with mouse?

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
/* optional: show position indicator in red */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: rgba(0,142,136,1.00);
}

div.scrollmenu {
 background: rgba(229,229,225,1.00);
 padding: 5px;
 overflow: scroll;
   white-space: nowrap;
 border-top: dotted 5px orange;
 border-bottom:solid 2px orange;
 color: orange;
 
}


div.scrollmenu a {
    background: white;
    display: inline-flex;
    color: blueviolet;
 font-size: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px  #ccffff ;
    
}
.product_img{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="scrollmenu">
  <a href="#home">1</a>
  <a href="#home">2 </a>
  <a href="#home">3</a>
  <a href="#home">4</a>
  <a href="#home">5</a>
  <a href="#home">6</a>
  <a href="#home">7</a>
  <a href="#home">8</a>
  <a href="#home">9</a>
    <a href="#home">10</a>
 </div>
```

but its cant scrolling by mouse when i hide the blue scrollbar, just worked on mobile and other touch screen.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox might be a good start for you to consider. Here's a good example. You can adjust the styles as needed

HTML

```
<ul class="flex-container">
   <li class="flex-item">1</li>
   <li class="flex-item">2</li>
   <li class="flex-item">3</li>
   <li class="flex-item">4</li>
   <li class="flex-item">5</li>
   <li class="flex-item">6</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.flex-container {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;

 display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;

-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {
background: tomato;
padding: 5px;
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
margin-top: 10px;

line-height: 150px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 3em;
text-align: center;
}
```

[image: Flexbox]

Comment: its not god enough to me